# Flask Jinja2 template syntax conflicts with AngularJS (jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError:)

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, jinja2

### How to access a $scope.list in html from angularjs?

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'car' is undefined

**main.js**

```
(function () 
{
    'use strict';

    angular.module('WordcountApp', [])    
    
    .controller('WordcountController', ['$scope', 
                                        function($scope) 
                                        {
                                            $scope.some = 'jjj'
                                              
                                            console.log( "in WordcountController " , $scope.some)
                                              
                                            $scope.cars = [
                                                            {make: 'Mazda', model: 'Miata', year: 2001},
                                                            {make: 'Toyota', model: 'Prius', year: 2013},
                                                            {make: 'Tesla', model: 'S', year: 2015},
                                                            {make: 'BMW', model: '325i', year: 2012}
                                                          ]
                                        }
                                       ]
                );
}()
);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "WordcountApp" >

    <head>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"> </script>
        <script src = "static/main.js" > </script>
    </head>
    
    <body ng-controller = "WordcountController">
        <ul ng-repeat = "car in cars" >
            <p> {{ car.make }} </p>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import render_template   
from flask import request           

app = Flask( __name__ )
displayText = 'Default text from Python'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/writeOutput", methods=['POST'])
def writeOutput():
    global displayText
    
    print("request.get_json():- ", request.get_json())
    
    displayText = request.get_json()['myOutput']['myText']
    
    print ("from POST " , displayText)
    return displayText


@app.route("/displayPreviousText", methods=['GET'])
def displayPreviousText():
    global displayText
    return displayText 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I run this application as `python app.py`

> Error: `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'car' is undefined`

What is the way to access the list in html from angular?

Comment: your code just works if I copy it... so problem is elsewhere

Comment: Could you post your package.json and any build/server config files? Its not clear how Jinja is part of the code you posted. (i.e. Are you serving with python?)

Comment: @kskid19 I am sorry for not including the python code. I have done it now. Kindly see. I am using Flask.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Please see the update. Thank you for trying my code.

Comment: You can open your index.html, you can `view page source` and click the link of `static/main.js`. make sure you can open that file, if not, then you should to learn how to read static files.

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula I am able to open that file. What is your point?

Comment: I think it's because it can't access the controller. But not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You error `Error: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'car' is undefined` is not related to JavaScript. The problem seems to be as follows -  [**Jinja2 template renderer also relies on double curly braces same as AngularJS**](https://www.palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/) `{{ your expression here }}`.

There are several solutions that could be used to solve this

1. You may change the interpolate notation for Angular i.e.

   ```
   angular.module('WordcountApp', [])
      .config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
         $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
         $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
      }]);
   ```

   So your javascript/html code should look as follows

   ```js
   (function () 
   {
     'use strict';

     angular.module('WordcountApp', [])

     // Setting up new interpolation delimiter which does not conflict with Jinja2
     .config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
       $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
       $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
     }])

     .controller('WordcountController', ['$scope',  function($scope) {
           $scope.some = 'jjj'
       
           console.log( "in WordcountController " , $scope.some)
       
           $scope.cars = [
               {make: 'Mazda', model: 'Miata', year: 2001},
               {make: 'Toyota', model: 'Prius', year: 2013},
               {make: 'Tesla', model: 'S', year: 2015},
               {make: 'BMW', model: '325i', year: 2012}
           ]                                         
     }])

   }()
   );
   ```

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html ng-app = "WordcountApp" >

       <head>
           <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"> </script>
           <script src = "static/main.js" > </script>
       </head>

       <body ng-controller = "WordcountController">
           <ul ng-repeat = "car in cars" >
               <!-- Utilizing new interpolation delimiter -->
               <p> [[ car.make ]] </p>
           </ul>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Also, I believe that a more simple way should work like

   ```
   <ul ng-repeat = "car in cars" >
       <p> {{ '{{ car.make }}' }} </p>
   </ul>
   ```

   which will use Jinja2 templater first and the output for the raw HTML would be correct AngularJS syntax. But I'm not 100% sure about this way and cannot check it right now.
3. Also while researching your problem I've found one more solution which could be used for solving your problem. Flask-Triangle provides a filter angular to tell Jinja if the evaluation of an expression must be rendered as an Angular expression. The undefined variables are rendered as-is in the HTML output.

   In this case your html part code should look as follows

   ```
   <body ng-controller = "WordcountController">
       <ul ng-repeat = "car in cars" >
           <p> {{car.make|angular}} </p>
       </ul>
   </body>
   ```

   You can read more about this solution

   - [Flash Triangle In-depth Tutorial -- AngularJS Templating in Jinja](https://flask-triangle.readthedocs.io/en/develop/tutorial/part1.html)

Comment: I am very thankful for all the effort you have presented here. Thanks for all the helpful links and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This happened because flask syntax conflicted with angular.

**So changes to Python code:**

```html
import os

from flask import Flask 
from flask import render_template
from flask import send_file, make_response, abort  
from flask import request           

app = Flask( __name__ )
displayText = 'Default text from Python'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
 return make_response(open('index.html').read())

@app.route("/writeOutput", methods=['POST'])
def writeOutput():
    global displayText

    print("request.get_json():- ", request.get_json())

    displayText = request.get_json()['myOutput']['myText']

    print ("from POST " , displayText)
    return displayText


@app.route("/displayPreviousText", methods=['GET'])
def displayPreviousText():
    global displayText
    return displayText 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

> return make_response(open('index.html').read())

instead of

> render_template('index.html')

This would solve the issue.

Another way could be using partials of Angular.

Comment: Thanks to you. It would have been better if you would explained what is  this `make_response(open('index.html').read())`  doing. Kindly add the explanation in your answer.

Comment: make response is used to send template as string not render it as flask2 template, I got it from https://github.com/shea256/angular-flask/blob/cf81930a21bef2a11fb7e839fdeae034c0a84d34/angular_flask/controllers.py#L25

Comment: This does is sends response as a string instead of parsing and inserting python variables.